How to use condition in column in group by with agg request
it's a bit hard to explain, i dont know how to use a condition in a column-select attribute in a SQL who have group by and aggregat functions...



Session
DateStart
DateEnd
TradeID
TradeKP




1
2024-12-09 11:20:15.000
2024-12-09 11:20:16.000
tr1
ICM


1
2024-12-09 11:20:07.000
2024-12-09 11:20:48.000
tr53
ICT


1
2024-12-09 11:22:07.000
2024-12-09 11:24:48.000
.
ICM


2
2024-12-08 04:55:09.000
2024-12-08 04:55:11.000
jik67
SMC


2
2024-12-08 04:55:13.000
2024-12-08 04:55:38.000
.
PLM



I want to return grouping with session :

The earliest Startdate (Using MIN aggregat, is ok it work)
The most recent EndDate (Using MAX aggregat, is ok it work)
The TradeKP which corresponds on the line who have "." in TradeID. (It's the problem how to do that?)
For information, one session can have 1 to 600 lines.
One session only have one line with "." in TradeID
The line who have "." maybe anywhere and therefore has no link with the date. The number total of row of this table can reach up to 500 millions of lines.

Exemple :



Session
Beginning
Ending
TradingMaster




1
2024-12-09 11:20:07.000
2024-12-09 11:24:48.000
ICM


2
2024-12-08 04:55:09.000
2024-12-08 04:55:38.000
PLM



I tried with this request, but it doesn't work :
SELECT session,
       MIN(DateStart) as beginning,
       MAX(DateEnd) as ending,
       MAX(tradeKP) as TradingMaster
FROM SCHEMA.TRADES
GROUP BY session


You can take value of column tradeID only for rows with condtition tradeID='.' ignoring (null) all other's.
Try
SELECT session,
       MIN(DateStart) as beginning,
       MAX(DateEnd) as ending,
       MAX(case when tradeID='.' then tradeKP end) as TradingMaster
FROM SCHEMA.TRADES
GROUP BY session


whooow thanks it s work ! great
